# Custom validation in Joi is not returning error message

Tags: node.js, joi

I was trying to make the email unique using Joi validation by making custom validation function checking if it exists in the database and even though the

```js
console.log(user);
```

is working, I'm not getting the validation error of the custom function I made.

this is my code

```js
const isUniqueEmail = async (value, helpers) => {
  const user = await User.query().where("email", value).first();

  if (user) {
    console.log(user);
    return helpers.error("any.invalid");
  }

  return value;
};
```

I got this **return helpers.error("any.invalid");** from Joi docs but it's not working
and this is my object

```js
const videosSchema = Joi.object({
  channel_id: Joi.number().required().label("Channel Id"),
  email: Joi.string().required().custom(isUniqueEmail),
  title: Joi.string().required().min(5).max(50),
});
```

it's not giving me the error when the email is already used even though it's logging the user

But the other validations are working

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anycustommethod-description) said:

> **any.custom(method, [description])**
> Adds a custom validation function to execute arbitrary code where:
>
> - **method** - the custom (synchronous only) validation function using signature function(value, helpers)

In your case, **isUniqueEmail** is not synchronous. I suggest to move your validation in your business layer code.